# Url rewriting using UrlRewriteFilter

Tags: url-rewriting, seo, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a website with pages serving dynamic content using query string.
Ex:
www.example.com?param1=abc&param2=xyz

I want to rewrite this url so that users and search engine should see the page with url:
www.example.com/abc/xyz

I am using Tomcat server so I chose [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)  to perform the rewrite. I am redirecting 
www.example.com/abc/xyz
to
www.example.com?param1=abc&param2=xyz

However, I am not sure which kind of redirect should I apply. On searching, I found that 301 is the most preferred one for seo. I tried using type="permament-redirect" but the url in address bar changes to the url with query string after redirection (which I don't want). The seo friendly url is retained in the address bar only if I apply type="forward" but I do not know if this is good for SEO.

My main purpose is to make my pages SEO friendly.
Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Once you ask and someone waste time trying to solve your question, u should give some feedback of the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

If google has already the URL for example:
www.example.com?param1=abc&param2=xyz

You will need to do a 301 for 
www.example.com/abc/xyz

And with UrlRewriteFilter you could still working with 
www.example.com/abc/xyz

And from the filter u can map folders as parameters with passthrough.

Also you should think to use the rel canonical for say which is the URL if you uses parameters, because for google read as differents URL for example:

www.example.com?param1=abc
www.example.com?param2=abc

or for example
www.example.com/abc/page.html?param1=abc
www.example.com/abc/page.html?param2=abc

But probably the content is very similar and you will be penalised for duplicate content so in the second case should have

www.example.com/abc/page.html?param1=abc ->    [canonical = www.example.com/abc/page.html]
www.example.com/abc/page.html?param2=abc ->    [canonical = www.example.com/abc/page.html]